# Jasmine trigger the search member function but can't get any response or error

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine and I am testing via UI so after entering the values in the search input field and triggering keyup event the search function is called which I confirmed by logging at different points but the API call is not triggered which is inside the search function. Do I have to use await or something like that?

dashboard.spec file

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    inputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[name=search]');
    inputElement.focus()
    inputElement.value = '131420'
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    keyUp().then(async () => {
      expect(component.searchText).toEqual(inputElement.value)
    });
  });

  it('should update the input', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log(component, 'component')
  })

  function keyUp() {
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { 'key': 'Space' }));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    inputElement.blur();
    return fixture.whenStable();
  }
```

search function that called on triggering keyup event from UI:

```
 search(event) {
    if (event) {
      console.log(event, 'event');
    }
    vm.tabHeight = 385;
    vm.selectedContract = 0;
    vm.member = {};
    vm.finance = null;
    vm.accountId = null;
    vm.searchLoading = true;
    var searchText = vm.searchText;
    console.log(searchText, 'searchText')
    if (searchText) {
      searchText = searchText.replace(/\(/g, '');
      searchText = searchText.replace(/\)/g, '');
      searchText = searchText.replace(/\-/g, '');
      searchText = searchText.replace(/\&/g, '');
      console.log('here')
      vm.dashboardService.search(searchText)
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log('got search response', res);
          vm.searchResult = res.hits;
          vm.searchLoading = false;
        }, err => {
          console.error('got search error', err);
          vm.searchLoading = false;
        });
    } else {
      vm.searchLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing asynchronous stuff in `beforeEach`. To do so, there is a callback function you should use which will be invoked when all async work has been completed :

```
beforeEach((done) => {
  promise.then(() => {
     done();
  });
}
```

Also, you probably should'nt write assertions (expect) in a setup function (beforeEach) but in your test case (it).